# Locally convex smooth surface has nonnegative Gaussian Curvature.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Definition: A smooth surface is **locally convex** at $p$ if its
>   intersection with some ball containing $p$ is contained in one of the
>   two closed half spaces whose boundary is $T_p(S)$.

I want to show that the Gaussian curvature at $p$ is nonnegative, but I really had a hard time understanding this notion of convexity.